# Add class after traversing up mand down a tree

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<li>
    <div class="classA">
        <div class="classB"></div>
        <div class="classC"></div>
        <div class="classD">
            <div class="classE"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to click on div with class `classE` and add a class to div with class `classB`

This is what I'm trying but it's failing:

```
$(document).on('click', '.classE', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.classB').addClass('addMe');
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.classE', function() {
    $(this).closest('classA').find('.classB').addClass('addMe');
});
```

I figured they're both parents, albeit removed, of `classB` so should find it?

Comment: Is it a typo on the last bit of code where you search for `('classA')`, without a full-stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use:

```
$(this).closest('.classB').addClass('addMe');
```

update:

```
 $(this).parent().siblings('.classB').addClass('addMe');
```

Comment: Apologies, I was incorrect with original structure, updated OP

Comment: yeah thats should be working for me, I can see the structure logic, but it's not??

Comment: woul be great if you create a fiddle.

Comment: Working now, was a cache issue I think, god damn firefox - many thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Closest should work as well and you did not need to go all the way up to classA. the .parent() works as well in the given code

```
$(document).on('click', '.classE', function() {
    $(this).closest('.classB').addClass('addMe');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.classE', function() {
  $(this).closest('.classB').addClass('addMe');
}
```

Comment: Can you add more value than straight code? The answer before yours is this exactly.